# Get screen resolution, replace string in file

Tags: php

So, here's my PHP code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<?php
copy('js/plugins.js', 'js/web_settings.js');
readfile("./game.html");
?>
</html>
```

What I want to do is first get the width and height of the user's screen resolution (or the size of the browser window if screen resolution isn't possible.) I then want it to check to make sure that the width is in the range of 800-1366 while the height is in the range of 640-768. If the variables are not in the range, they will be adjusted so that they are either the minimum value or the maximum value, depending on whether it is smaller or larger then the range. Then, I want it to compare the width and height, and assign the larger number to variable 1, then assign the smaller number to variable 2. Then, it will run the copy code in my script so it replaces the output file if it already exists, however, it will replace the numbers in the string `"Screen Width":"1366","Screen Height":"768" (from plugins.js)` so 1366 is replaced with the value of variable 1, and 768 is replaced with the value of variable 2. How can I achieve this in PHP? (Note that the string was copied directly from the file and was unaltered.)

Comment: This is not how it works. JS executes on client-side (browser), but PHP executes on server-side. It means that you don't have access to data like width/height  of the window in PHP simply because it runs on server before sending the result to the client.

Comment: You cannot directly get the user's screen resolution in PHP because PHP code runs in the server.

Comment: @Dai Got it, I guess I'll have to experiment.